# Virtual memory ring buffer on windows

Tags: windows, winapi, memory

I'm trying to implement a ring buffer on Windows that uses virtual memory mirroring so that the application can access segments that cross the wrapping point as contiguous memory.

[Windows ring buffer without copying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016888/windows-ring-buffer-without-copying)

describes how to implement it using the Windows API (I already have the Linux/POSIX implementation).
However, on according to [its documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366763(v=vs.85).aspx), `MapViewOfFileEx` is not guaranteed to work, because the `lpBaseAddress` may become unsafe after the mapping:

> While it is possible to specify an address that is safe now (not used by the operating system), there is no guarantee that the address will remain safe over time.

When can this occur that the address becomes "unsafe", and how can it be prevented?

Comment: I'm guessing here, but I'd say that if `MapViewOfFileEx` succeeds, the address you specified **is** safe for as long as you have the view mapped. If the OS is already using that address then the function will fail, and you'll have to pick a different address.

Comment: Yes, by "over time" they mean "when the operating system is updated" or perhaps "when new software is installed on your machine" or "when you try to run the program on a different machine".  If the call succeeds, you don't have a problem.  But you *do* have to cope with the case where the call fails, typically by falling back to copying the data as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10 it becomes possible to guarantee being able to create adjacent allocation regions using the placeholder flags.

You first reserve a the full addressable region using the `MEM_RESERVE | MEM_RESERVE_PLACEHOLDER` flags.

Then you split that allocation in half with a `VirtualFree(placeholder1, bufferSize, MEM_RELEASE | MEM_PRESERVE_PLACEHOLDER);`

then you can `MapViewOfFile3` the same null mapping to both halves of the placeholder region using the `MEM_REPLACE_PLACEHOLDER` flag.

A full example is available on the [windows docs of VirtualAlloc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc2)